# junos pulse client or network client

Tags: 16.10

I have a problem. I cant find network client or junos pulse client. All of my friend change the server system windows to ubuntu but we dont because of no client for connect to vpn ubuntu.I realy want to use ubuntu but have not any client to connect the vpn

Answer (score -1):

https://www.pulsesecure.net/products/pulse-secure-client/

(you need an account to download)

worked for me pretty well until Ubuntu 16.10, but with 16.10 it it seems to be broken and i can find out why...

But with 12.04 - 16.04 it worked like a charm